# How to design an abstract method when you don't know the type of parameters it will contain (building a Framework)

Tags: java, design-patterns, frameworks

I'm designing a framework for managing certain api calls and other long-running tasks on our mobile clients. I will be designing and implementing it on a basic java program which then can be passed onto the client developers to extend the classes in the framework and implement their concrete classes where they do context-specific stuff.

There is a place where the manager would send notifications to the components that are waiting on a task. Now in the `AbstractManager` I have a method called `registerClient(Messenger m)` where a client can register itself as a listener so they can know when a task is finished.

Now if I want to keep it abstract, I can't say that it's a `Messenger` object, each app and platform might use a different implementation of notification. How can I design this so that `registerClient` can be implemented in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could provide a an interface (e.g. `IMessenger`) that each messenger object is required to implement and make that the type of the parameter

```
registerClient(IMessenger m)
```

If you chose the right methods for the interface (mostly the same as you have for `Messenger` now), you can provide multiple implementations of the interface that you can use in the `registerClient()` method

Comment: yeah but this might be hard to do because for example on android the messenger is a class from the OS and it's basically generated from a Handler class.. It might not be possible to have the Handler implement the IMessenger

Comment: If there are no common base classes/interfaces to the messenger classes, then you will not be able to write your `registerClient` in a generic way.  Maybe you can use `Handler` instead?  I'm not familiar with the particulars of android

Comment: I guess this is where the issue is.. Even just on android, for one app, the client might be using what's called a `Broadcast` to send messages or another might use a `Messenger`.. This gets even more confusing when Blackberry is implementing the framework. I only know that we will collect some type of object and call a certain function on them. Maybe generics might be the way to go for something like this?

Comment: Even for generics you would need some commonality between the two classes to do anything useful.  It seems like you will need to create two separate manager types: one for the registration/handling of `Messenger` clients and another for `Broadcast` clients.  Alternatively, provide two separate `registerClient()` methods for the same `Manager`: one for registering `Messenger`s the other for `Broadcast`s, then keep a separate collection of registered `Messenger`s and another for registered `Broadcast`s

Comment: i think i might just make an abstract class called `notifyClients` and it will be up to the concrete abstractions to figure out how to implement it (also keep track of clients and so on)

Comment: I meant to say an abstract method called `notifyClients`, not a class

Answer (score 3):

Make it generic so your method will be registerClient(T messenger)

Answer (score 2):

When creating an API **Interfaces** and **Generics** are your best friends. Of course, you don't know exactly what is going to come through, but by giving users interfaces that they must implement, you can be sure that you can do what you need with whatever concrete implementations they do decide to use.